# Python log analysis tool/library

Tags: python, mysql, apache, logging, elasticsearch

I'm looking for a tool/library written in python similar with logstash (ruby + java).

My goals are:

- parse all system logs from syslog
- parse application specific logs (apache, django, mysql etc.)
- store results in something like elasticsearch
- graph results based on different criteria

thanks!

ps: regexes are a way to go but I feel will be quite of work to start from scratch

Comment: Can you give an example for the last point ("graph results based on different criteria")? What information would you like to extract?

Comment: anything really ... e.g how long it takes to server requests for a web page per ip.

Comment: Given that this is really broad, why aren't you using a [logstash shipper](http://cookbook.logstash.net/recipes/log-shippers/)?

Comment: hi - i looked at https://github.com/josegonzalez/beaver but is just an agent really ... a better solution could be https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logtools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shameless plug (I am the author of the library) - 
logtools does everything you mentioned and much, much more. I try to keep the documentation up to date and show alot of examples, similar to use cases you describe, in the README file. hopefully it would fit what you have in mind, give it a try, and any feedback is welcome - I try to add/fix any issues brought up by users. Check it out at http://github.com/adamhadani/logtools or download latest stable release at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logtools

Comment: Hi, @Adam Ever-Hadani, do you still maintain this library ? It's seems no compatible with python >= 3.7. What happened ?